# ama.bst puts extra space after single author

Tags: bibtex

I am using [ama.bst](https://ctan.org/pkg/ama?lang=en) to format bibliography in my manuscript, and it seems to be adding unnecessary space for publications with single author.

[image]

I suspect there is something wrong with the function that formats names, but haven't been able to figure:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=  % push the name s, pop s and author (already on stack), assign author to s
  #1 'nameptr :=
  #0 'etal :=

  s num.names$ 'numnames :=

  numnames #6 >
    {#3 'numnames :=
     #1 'etal :=
    }
    {}
    %end if 
  if$

  numnames 'namesleft :=
  { namesleft #0 > }

  {s nameptr "{ll~}{ff}" format.name$ 't :=
    namesleft #1 >
    {t * ", " * }
    {t}
    %end if 
    if$
    nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
    namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
  }
  while$

  etal
    {", et al. "}
    {". "}
  if$
  *
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Doea this happen with every entry with a single author? I assume that it happens here, because the author only has a last name (that is "R Core Team") and no first name. As the format is defined as `"{ll~}{ff}"` where `~` depicts a protected space, it seems evident that this space is put after the last name, even if there is no first name following.

Comment: Just an idea, without having tested it: couldn't you just write `"{ll}{~ff}"` instead of `"{ll~}{ff}"`? As long as there are no authors that are referred to only by their first name, this could work.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hack

```
author={{R Core Team}, \unskip}
```

or you can edit the `.bst` file (a copy with a different name, say `ama-mod.bst`) to have the line

```
  {s nameptr "{ll~}{ff}" format.name$ 't :=
```

changed into

```
  {s nameptr "{ll}{~ff}" format.name$ 't :=
```

so the space is added only if a first name is present. Your entry can now have the standard

```
author={{R Core Team}}
```

Comment: Nice trick. Thank you!